# Change Datatable after changing inputSelect

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, shiny

I have a sidebar where I have a inputSelect with items from my list. 
In the main part of Shiny, I would like to see the table changing when I change my choose in the inputSelect.
I managed to do this with normal text in the header.
Any one

```
#App
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel(" "),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      h4 ("Selecteer een klant uit lijst"),

      selectInput("select", 
                  label = "Kies een klant",
                  choices = list.Hikerlocaties,
                  selected = 0),
      # checkboxInput("Student", "Alleen studenten", value = TRUE),
      actionButton("zoek", "Zoek")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("select"),
      datatable(SelectedKlant, options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = 'tip', order = list(2,'desc')), rownames = FALSE, width = 500, colnames = c('Naam', 'Klant', 'Aantal'), elementId = "results")
      )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$select <- renderText(input$select)
  SelectedKlant <- reactive({
    a <- subset(freq3, Klantref == input$select)
    return(a)
  })
  output$results <- renderDataTable(SelectedKlant, options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = 'tip', order = list(2,'desc')), rownames = FALSE, width = 500, colnames = c('Naam', 'Klant', 'Aantal'), elementId = "results")
} 

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The example you provide is not self-contained. You should either provide some of the data, or even better create a much simpler [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)
2. Reactive expression are like functions, so you need to call `SelectedKlant()` to get the answer `a`. See [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html)
3. In the UI, you just need to call for `DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")`
    as in [this simple example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html)
4. All in all, this summarizes the above:

   ```
   library(shiny)
   library(DT)

   ui <- basicPage(
     sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("select", 
                 label = "Select species",
                 choices = c('setosa','versicolor','virginica'))
   ),
   mainPanel(
     textOutput("selected_text"),
     DT::dataTableOutput("results")
       )
     )
   )

   server <- function(input, output) {
     output$selected_text <- renderText(input$select)

     SelectedKlant <- reactive({
       a <- subset(iris, Species == input$select)
       return(a)
     })

     output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(SelectedKlant(), options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = 'tip', order = list(2,'desc')), rownames = FALSE, width = 500, elementId = "results")
   } 

   # Run the application 
   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
   ```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Your work did a perfect job for me @Javier!
Thanks for helping me out, and, most important, learn me something!